# How to create custom FileField which modifies the uploaded file in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I want to modify the contents of files when they are uploaded.  I have many models using several FileFields that all need this behaviour so I don't want to use signals or override the model `save()` on each model.  I want to create a custom FileField to handle this behaviour.

I am trying to do this by extending FileField and overriding the `pre_save()` method.  I am able to read the file contents but when I write to the file it remains unchanged.  Below is a basic example.

fields.py

```
from django.db.models import FileField

class CustomFileField(FileField):
    def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
        file = super().pre_save(model_instance, add)
        file.write(b'foo')
        return file
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from fields import CustomFileField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = CustomFileField(upload_to='files')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a custom FileField I took the following approach of creating a custom field with no logic and an abstract model where the file is modified in the `save()` method.  I still feel this logic should belong in a custom field and this is hacky.  But it does work.

fields.py

```
from django.db.models import FileField

class CustomFileField(FileField):
    pass
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from fields import CustomFileField

class CustomFileFieldModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
         update_fields=None):
    super().save(force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update, using=using, update_fields=update_fields)

    fields = self._meta.get_fields()

    for field in fields:
        if field.__class__ == CustomFileField:

            file = getattr(self, field.name)

            with file.open(mode='w') as f:
                f.write('foo')

class MyModel(CustomFileFieldModel):
    my_field = CustomFileField(upload_to='files')
```